# AFNetworking: Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

After adding `AFNetworking`, `Apple Mach-O Linker Error` occured. 
I've already added SystemConfiguration.framework, MobileCoreServices.framework, and Security.framework.
How do I fix it?

Comment: do you have all the SD files properly imported into the project? are they at Compile Sources under BuildPhases?

Comment: which of AFNetworking version you have used

Comment: What error does the Mach-O linker gives? Edit your question by adding Log of this Mach-O-Linker.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this one. In this case, this call belongs to the Accelerate framework so on top of your file, enter:

```
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
```